# Memory Segment allocation for global and local Pointer Variables in C

Tags: c

Can you please clarify below questions.

1) Where is the memory segment of local pointer located. e.g. where is p located in `int main () { int *p; }`

2) Where is the memory location for the global pointer variable?.

3) How can local pointer variable access the global variables in case of different memory segments?

4) global pointer variables, what is the scope and how can use it??

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: These are questions from homework or an interview

Comment: @Frankie_C: What is your point? Neither of this is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I thought that we don't do homework here, but the question can be interpreted as a request of better explanation maybe.

Comment: @Frankie_C: [Asking about homework is fine.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) [It is explicitly mentioned in the help on “What topics can I ask about here?”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Frankie_C .. yes i am expected better explanation..// thanks for your tricky doubt about this!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

1) Most commonly, C implementations store regular local objects of functions on a stack. (The C standard permits any implementation that achieves the required effects.<sup>1</sup>)

2) Most commonly, C implementations use a general data segment for global objects. Such data segments are created by the program loader from information in the executable file. There are various formats for executable files, but they commonly contain segments with read-only data, segments with data that will be writeable in the program but that has initial values, and segments for data that will be writeable but that is initialized to zero or perhaps uninitialized. The software that loads the program into memory in preparation for execution reads the executable file, requests memory from the operating system, and lays out all the segments. (Again, the C standard permits any implementation that achieves the required effects.)

3) A local pointer can refer to a global object because they share a single address space within the process. The local and global objects are merely put in different places within the address space, not in different spaces.

4) The scope of the name of a global object is the translation unit in which its declaration appears, starting at the place where it is declared and extending to the end of the translation unit. (A translation unit is a source file along with any other files it includes with the `#include` directive.)

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Some people make a hullabaloo of the C standard not requiring a stack. However, the C standard does specify stack semantics for function calls: The behavior of objects local to functions is last-in-first-out, which is the behavior of a stack. Because a hardware stack provides the required features of a stack data structure and hence matches the needs of the C standard, it is the natural way to implement function calls and their objects. Aside from the fact that optimization may actually eliminate local objects or put them in registers instead of memory, essentially the only time you would see a C implementation without a stack is in a very constrained special-purpose environment.

Comment: Yes, C kind of specifies a stack of activation records but it is nowhere said that it need to be contiguous memory or that they need to be cleaned inside out. In fact the C standard does not rule out closures or different cleanup order either - an implementation that has closures would conform to the specs.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 & 2) There is no concept of *stack* in the C standards. Also, the location where the different variable types are stored is **implementation dependent**

Q3) A local pointer will hold the address of global variables (if assigned correctly). Taking the value of this pointer, you can access global variables.

Q4) Global variables have a scope throughout the entire program. They can be accessed from anywhere. They also have a lifetime of the entire program.

Comment: The scope of the name of a “global” object is the translation unit in which it is declared (starting from the declaration, ending at the end of the translation unit). It is not the entire program. The same name can be declared in multiple translation units, and the names are made to refer to the same object through linkage, but each instance has a different scope, in the different translation units.

Comment: Although the C standard does not specify how memory is laid out by an implementation and how objects are stored, there are **overwhelmingly** common methods used, and it is important that students learn these and how they affect program behavior. Answers to such inquiries ought to teach these methods, not spurn the questions based on technicalities.